# how to load php array into javascript variable on runtime

Tags: php, android, jquery, ios, web-applications

i have a website/(mobile, app created with phone gap build), in this site i load some arrays with php into javascript to show some ads. on website it's work very well, but on the mobile apps (iOS and android) i got an empty space. if i fill the array variables in js directly, it works in all versions of the site web and mobile.

the problem is i have about 460  different ads to show. i like to load about 20 ads into js when users start or load the site/app in php i read the mysql db and load these ads witch shown less. after showing the ads, ads-couter +1 .(didn't show it here)

the reason why i'm doing this so, is, because i did'n find something to monetize my html5 css3 query web app, compiled with phone gap build.

now can someone show me or explain me why it works on web but not on app, or why it works both when i fill the variable in js direct??

my php works fine -> to js

in js i have this:

```
// werbung
function werbung_fill(){

     id =  new Array;
     comment_start = new Array;
     bannerLinks =  new Array;
     adBanners =  new Array;
     bannerTargets =  new Array;
     dimension =  new Array;
     comment_end =  new Array;
     aktiv =  new Array;
     angezeigt =  new Array;
     lasttime =  new Array;

               $.getJSON('inc/werbung_call.php', function(data) {
         /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
     $.each(data, function(key, val) {

     id.push(val.id);                   
     comment_start.push(val.comment_start);
     bannerLinks.push(val.bannerLinks);
     adBanners.push(val.adBanners);
     bannerTargets.push(val.bannerTargets);
     dimension.push(val.dimension);
     comment_end.push(val.comment_end);
     aktiv.push(val.aktiv);
     angezeigt.push(val.angezeigt);
     lasttime.push(val.lasttime);

            });
        });
}

function werbung(){

  var randNum     = Math.floor(Math.random() * (19 - 0 + 1)) + 0; 
  var topAdBanner = $('#topad > a > img');
  var newcomment_start = comment_start[randNum];
  var newBannerImg  = adBanners[randNum];
  var newBannerLink = bannerLinks[randNum];
  var newBannerTarget = bannerTargets[randNum];
  var newdimension = dimension[randNum];
    var newcomment_end = comment_end[randNum];

  // update new img src and link HREF value
    $(topAdBanner).attr('src',newBannerImg);
    $('#topad > a').attr('href',newBannerLink);
    $('#topad > a').attr('target',newBannerTarget);
    $('#topad > a').attr('alt',newdimension);

    var deinTimer = window.setTimeout(werbung, 5000);
    //$('#topad1').html(id[randNum]);
}
```

in

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
// werbungs banner
$('<div id="topad"><a href="" target=""><img src="" width="320" height="50" alt="" border="0"></a></div><!-- @end #topad -->').prependTo( $( "#hauptheader" ) );

// werbung
werbung_fill();
werbung();
// werbung

}
```

with this, i can inject a div without compiling the apps again. (it works fine)

the js, php, index.html are on the same server and the compiled apps use the js css images from server too.

Comment: ** Noone ?? Can help ?? **

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors in your JavaScript.  You should validate your JavaScript here: http://www.jshint.com/

I suspect Android isn't parsing this correctly:

```
id =  new Array;
```

Suggest using this syntax instead:

```
var id =  [];
```

Comment: Sorry, but it dont changes somthing, id = []; is same as id = new Array; and var id = []; -> Array lifes only in that function. But thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily. Android may require that you declare new arrays as `id = new Array()` rather than just `id = new Array`.  I believe Chrome is smart enough to recognize both as the same, but I suspect Android might be failing to parse this?